# Text getting overlapped in Jupyter Notebook suddenly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

Jupyter notebook started behaving weirdly very suddenly. The text started to get overlapped.
Screenshot for reference:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: standard I.T. response:   shut everything down and restart it...

Comment: Already tried the standard stuff, nothing happening

Comment: have you tried using notebook in `vs code` with the same as above ?